# jQuery data-image-zoom attribute change

Tags: jquery, html, image, attributes, zooming

hi i use attr method is not changing

html code

```
<a href="<?php echo $popup; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" class="colorbox">
      <img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" alt="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" id="image"  data-zoom-image="<?php echo $popup; ?>" class="product-image-zoom"/></a>
```

jQuery Code

```
$("#image").attr('data-zoom-image','MY IMAGE URL');
```

He does not know the reason for change?
Image not replace my new image

elevate zoom data-zoom-image

Comment: Your jQuery is (probably) updating the data-zoom-image attribute, but that doesn't mean that whatever code is using the data-zoom-image attribute knows it's been updated.

Comment: Where is the event who allows to change the image ?